# Unit Testing Location Service

Tags: android, unit-testing, geolocation

I've got a location tracking service that I'm trying to unit test.  I'm trying to use the locationManager.addTestProvider and setTestProviderLocation methods to achieve this.  I can't seem to get any of the locations to pass through the provider and hit my LocationListener, however.  Here is my code:

```
public void testGettingLocations() {
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (mLocationManager.getProvider(TEST_PROVIDER) != null) {
        mLocationManager.removeTestProvider(TEST_PROVIDER);
    }

    mLocationManager.addTestProvider(TEST_PROVIDER, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, Criteria.POWER_LOW, Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(TEST_PROVIDER, true);
    mLocationManager.setTestProviderStatus(TEST_PROVIDER, LocationProvider.AVAILABLE, null, System.currentTimeMillis());


    locations = new ArrayList<Location>();


    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(TEST_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);


    for (int i = 0; i<130; i++) {
        Location loc = new Location(TEST_PROVIDER);
        loc.setLatitude(0 + i);
        loc.setLongitude(130 - i);
        loc.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        loc.setSpeed(0);
        loc.setAccuracy(25);
        loc.setAltitude(0);
        loc.setBearing(0);
        mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation(TEST_PROVIDER, loc);       
    }

    assertEquals(130, locations.size());
}

LocationListener ll = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {   }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        locations.add(location);
        Log.d("TEST", "lat: " + location.getLatitude() + ", lon: " + location.getLongitude());
    }
};
```

The assert fails because locations.size() returns 0, and the log statement in my locationlistener never gets printed.

Has anyone had any success using these methods to unit test Location services?

Comment: I should also mention that I do have the ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATIONS permission on both the test project and the actual project.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I have the same problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get @ingsaurabh's example working in a unit test after making the following modifications:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public final class TestLocationProvider {
    static void sendLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 5554); // usually 5554
            socket.setKeepAlive(true);
            String str = "geo fix " + longitude + " " + latitude ;
            Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            w.write(str + "\r\n");
            w.flush();
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The important detail is the IP address.  The emulator does not recognize 'localhost' as a valid hostname.

Comment: it does recognized for me

Answer (score 4):

Hi in my first GPS based project I faced the same problem so I write a java code that will send GPS Fix to my android emulator below is the snippet.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Main {

static final int PAUSE = 4000; // ms
static final float START_LONGITUDE = 51, START_LATITUDE = -1.3f;
static final int NO_SAMPLE = 100;
static final float DELTA_LONGITUDE = 0.000005f, DELTA_LADITUDE = 0.000005f;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 5554); // usually 5554

        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        float longitude = START_LONGITUDE, latitude = START_LATITUDE;
        String str;

        for (int i = 0; i < NO_SAMPLE; i++) {
            str = "geo fix " + latitude + " " + longitude + "\n";
            out.print(str);
            System.out.print(str);

            Thread.sleep(PAUSE);

            longitude += DELTA_LONGITUDE;
            latitude += DELTA_LADITUDE;
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! Were you able to hook this into Android's JUnit testing successfully?  It seems like I'd have to run this in a separate process simultaneously, which isn't an ideal solution for me.

Comment: yeah, this will send mock GPS only to your normal GPS based app running on emulator at port 5554

Comment: I'm sorry, does that mean that you have hooked it into JUnit for automated testing?  If so, could you explain a little better how it hooks into your test cases?

Comment: why are you sending a string to emulator? Does emulator takes string?