# Android functional test; send geo location to emulator

Tags: android, geolocation, functional-testing

Our android application is getting fairly big and we would like to use functional tests for our application to prevent regression. We are looking in to options to achieve this.

We make use of geo locations, so now we test the app by entering lat/long in DDMS. If we want to test this, it should be possible to set these geo locations programmatically.

Is there a framework that we can use to functional test our android app and also send these updates to our emulator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am facing the same problem.  While this solution is not built into robotium, you should be able to make it into a utility that can be used in your unit tests.

[Unit Testing Location Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149432/unit-testing-location-service)

Answer (score 6):

If you compile in Eclipse, you can fake the lat/lon in the android emulator:

- Windows > Open perspective > Other.
- Choose DDMS
- Search Emulator control tab
- Use the location control to send Latitude and Longitude whenever you want.

Comment: we use DDMS already to set it manually, but we want to be able to set it after our application starts by the program. It is possible with monkeyrunner to send ADB commands, but is there an ADB command to send a location?

Comment: Well, you could put set it manually:
1º If you have update by GPS position, comment it.
2º Write a function to set position, create new class android.location.location, myclasslocation.setLatitude(latitude)
3º Launch the function pushing a button, in a Dialog or a new activity, you can put the intent in a optionmenu.

Comment: That could work, but I don't want to change my code to make a test work, does there exist a solution within monkeyrunner/robotium or androidrunner to instead of sending text to a textfield, sending geolocation to the emulator?

Comment: If exists another solution, i don´t know what solution is. You could do a testObject.java file, to test it.

Comment: 1º Create the test object, call a menu context, call the function to change, a test it. You will change only 2 lines on the original code. I can´t help you more.

Answer (score 0):

If you use monkeyrunner, then you might use this function:

```
def telnet(host, port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(2)

    # connect to remote host
    try :
        s.connect((host, port))
    except :
        print 'Unable to connect'
        sys.exit()

    print 'Connected to remote host'
    return s

def geo_fix(port, lat, lng):
    print "setting gps to " + str(lat) + "," + str(lng)
    socket = telnet("localhost", port)
    socket.send("geo fix " + str(lng) + " " + str(lat) + "\n")
    socket.send("exit\n")
    socket.close()

geo_fix(5554, 32.0878802, 34.797246)
```

I couldn't find a way to get the emulator's port from the MonkeyDevice, so I manually pass the port, but would be nicer if we could figure it out from the device object